# Average of n lowest priced hourly intervals in a day pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, trading

I have a dataframe that is made up of hourly electricity price data.  What I am trying to do is find a way to calculate the average of the n lowest price hourly periods in day.  The data spans many years and aiming to get the average of the n lowest price periods for each day.  Synthetic data can be created using the following:

```
np.random.seed(0)
rng = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=24, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Price': np.random.randn(len(rng)) })
```

I have managed to get the lowest price for each day by using:

```
df_max = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')]).min()
```

Is there a way to get the average of the n lowest periods in a day?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group the dataframe by `Grouper` object with daily frequency then aggregate `Price` using `nsmallest` to obtain the `n` smallest values, now calculate the `mean` on `level=0` to get the average of `n` smallest values in a day

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D'))['Price'].nsmallest(5).mean(level=0)
```

Result of calculating the average of `5` smallest values daily

```
Date
2020-01-01   -1.066337
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham. Works perfectly....and elegant!  Would welcome any suggestions on how this could be expanded to a dataframe with multiple price columns (other than looping through each of the columns).  But thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following:

bottom_5_prices_mean=df.sort_index(ascending=True).head(5)['Price'].mean()
top_5_prices_mean=df.sort_index(ascending=True).tail(5)['Price'].mean()

Comment: Thanks Sunil, Looks like a tidy solution but not sure that it would manage the daily frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The answer by Shubham is the perfect one. I just wanted to share the alternate. I am a quant analyst, This solution will work.